# How to run Apache Beam Python code on AWS EMR?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-beam, amazon-emr

I am just using a python file from creating Apache Beam Pipeline and trying to run it through the AWS EMR.

`hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-jars/command-runner.jar spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster s3://tmp-emr-poc/etl-json-to-parquet.py`

but it gives the error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:915)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:915)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkUserAppException: User application exited with 1
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner$.main(PythonRunner.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner.main(PythonRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:740)
```

How to make it work.

Comment: What is the contents of s3://tmp-emr-poc/etl-json-to-parquet.py ? Is it what spark-submit expects?

Comment: It's just a normal apache beam pipeline, read from s3-> convert to parquet -> write to s3. Just simple logic.

Comment: I think i am doing it the wrong way, I think i need to use direct python command. (i. e.: python s3://tmp-emr-poc/etl-json-to-parquet.py --runner=SparkRunner) something like this